# Really slow output when using popen?

Tags: c++, stream, popen

I am getting performance issues when using popen in C++. The output shown on the screen looks REALLY slow compared to when I open the subprocess directly. It looks like if it was refreshing every second and not constantly... I even tried not using endl, and sync_with_stdio(false) but nothing seems to make the output faster.

Here is my code:

```
int main() {

    FILE *in;

    char buff[4096];
    //cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

    if(!(in = popen("python websocket/test.py", "r"))){
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
        cout << "====>>" << buff << endl;
    }

    pclose(in);

    return 0;

}
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't know a lot about `popen` ,but I think `in = popen("python websocket/test.py", "r")` should be `in == popen("python websocket/test.py", "r")` with two "equals" mark `==`

Comment: @YazanWYusuf: no, confusing as it can be: "in" is being initialized and then checked for being zero. "==" would compare with an unitialized "in" variable.

Comment: make `python` to flush its stdout buffer sooner or unbuffer its output: `python -u websocket/test.py`. See the 2nd reason in [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Comment: I think it works!! What does the "-u" does??

Comment: [`-u` flag makes standard streams unbuffered](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)